# Why is the following inequality true: $\frac{k!}{k^k} > e^{-k}$

Tags: combinatorics, inequality

I stumbled upon the following inequality in a scientific paper which estimates a lower bound for $\frac{k!}{k^k}$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$: 
$$\frac{k!}{k^k} > e^{-k}$$
They did not explain why this holds true, and I could not find any answer by myself yet.

Comment: They're probably using [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite it as $$e^{k}>\frac{k^k}{k!}$$

And you see that it follows because $$e^{x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$$, and thus, for any $x\geq 0$, $e^{x}>\frac{x^k}{k!}$.

Answer (score 4):

$$e^k=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{k^i}{i!}>\frac{k^k}{k!}$$
result follows by taking reciprocal

Answer (score 3):

Use the Taylor series:

$$e^k = 1+k+\frac{k^2}{2!} +\cdots+\frac{k^k}{k!} +\cdots.$$

Because all terms on the right are positive, we have

$$e^k > \frac{k^k}{k!},$$

then just take reciprocals of both sides.

Answer (score 0):

> **There have already been several answers posted that relied on the Taylor series for $\displaystyle e^x$.  Herein, we take a different approach to establish the bound by using only straightforward arithmetic and Riemann sums.**

Let $f(k)=\frac{k!}{k^k}$.  Then, $\log(f(k))$ is given by

$$\begin{align}
\log(f(k))&=\log(k!)-\log(k^k)\\\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^k\log(j)-k\log(k)\\\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^k\log(j/k)\\\\
&=k\underbrace{\left(\frac1k \sum_{j=1}^k\log(j/k)\right)}_{\text{Right-Sided Riemann Sum for}\,\int_0^1\log(x)\,dx=-1}\\\\
&>-k
\end{align}$$

Hence, we have established that $f(k)>e^{-k}$ as was to be shown!

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. -Mark